# Why JsonConvert.DeserializeObject change the String value?

Tags: c#, json, rest, asp.net-web-api, json.net

I get proper result from REST Web Api, But when I try to Deserialize the result, It's change the string value "**034342323**" to "**7455955**"

**My Class**

```
public class DataModel
     {

         public int Id { get; set; }

         public string ABN { get; set; }

         public string AccountNumber { get; set; }

     }
```

**JSON Result**

```
[{"Id":1,"ABN":"9949876532","AccountNumber":"034342323"}]
```

**Calling code**

```
 using (HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync(url).ConfigureAwait(false))
                {
                    if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
                    {
                        var result = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

                        result = result.Replace("\"", string.Empty).Trim();
                        result = result.Replace("\\", string.Empty).Trim();

                        var data = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<IEnumerable<DataModel>>(result);

                      [...]


                    }
```

All the value remain same accept the AccountNumber change automatically

[image]

**Note:** We found if any string starting with **"0"** , during de-serialization it is change autometically !!!!

Now it is become

```
[{"Id":1,"ABN":"9949876532","AccountNumber":"7455955"}]
```

**Additional**

If I don't remove **""** it is unable to Desirialize & throws error

```
{"Error converting value \"[{\"Id\":1,\"ABN\":\"9949876532\",\"AccountNumber\":\"034342323\"}]\" to type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[DataModel]'
  . Path '', line 1, position 174."}

        Could not cast or convert from System.String to System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[DataModel].
```

**Solution**

```
   result = result.Replace("\"", "").Trim();
   result = result.Replace("\\", "'").Trim(); //This line is the tricks
```

**Thanks To Andrew** for his explanation. So I overcome this issue, by minor modification.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This behavior is by design: integer strings leading with "0" will be treated as octal numbers(`octal 34342323` == `decimal 7455955`) by Json.Net:

http://json.codeplex.com/workitem/22097

When you generate your json, please review the code that adds AccountNumber, make sure you remove leading `"0"`.

Comment: But it starts interpreting like this only after he removes quotes. As long as it string(in quotes) it should not matter, right?

Comment: it does. please have a look at section 3 here http://samuli.hakoniemi.net/10-small-things-you-may-not-know-about-javascript/

Comment: This sounds like the behavior witnessed, but it does not look by design at all - it looks like a bug. The work item you linked to talks about numbers where in OP's case they are deserializing a string.

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum, OP removes quotes in his code, meaning `"AccountNumber":"034342323"` becomes `AccountNumber:034342323`, and json.net starts treating the number as octal

Comment: @ Andrew: If I need 0 is their any way do that ?

Comment: You can define deserialization explicitly on the property. It's generally a really bad idea to manipulate your JSON with string methods.

Comment: yes, you can have a custom deserialization, or you can post-process your property to convert it from octal to decimal after deserialization....but what is the reason for having "0" in you json? is it a formatted string with certain amount of digits with tailing zeroes?

Comment: @Andrew : By business logic, It is have couple of number which may have "0" and those are valid like Bank Account No

Comment: then removing quotes in your json before deserialization is not a good idea at all. instead try deserializing as array type...or add leading zeroes like this `AccountNumber = AccountNumber.PadLeft(desiredLength, '0')`

Comment: @Andrew : if I don't remove quotes before deserialization, it's throw error. I updated my post. And add leading zeroes , then I have to flag or something, the original number containing 0 or not.